# Tcxtreelist overlap text over columns Devexpress

Tags: delphi, text, devexpress, ondraw, treelist

I have a populated tcxtreelist with all root nodes(any node which is set to level 0) being a parent to more desired information. The issue that I have is that the text is clipped by columns used for the children nodes.

I want to be able to have the text from the root nodes(LSite.Name) to span the length of all the columns, basically I want to remove the clipping. However I want the the children nodes to work as default.

How is this done?

Edit: Code added

```
LSite : TSiteList;
i : Integer;
LNode : TcxTreeListNode;
// variables used are above
for i := 0 to FSiteList.Count - 1 do
begin
LSite := TSiteList(FSiteList.Items[i]);then
LNode := TreeTypes.Add;
LNode.Values[0] := LSite.Name;
LNode.Data := LSite; // this is is location name built up from a database which populates FSiteList(Object list)
end
```

This is how the root node is populated. Thousands of records with some information used elsewhere but with regards to the list all I care about is the name fitting across all the columns.

Children nodes:

```
LOffer : TOfferList;
i : Integer;
LNode, LSiteNode : TcxTreeListNode;

begin
LSiteNode := TreeTypes.FocusedNode;
for i := 0 to FOfferList.Count - 1 do
begin
  LOffer := TOfferList(FOfferList.Items[i]);
  LNode := LSiteNode.AddChild;
  LNode.Values[1] := Trim(FOfferList.Items[i].InstName  + ' ' + FOfferList.Items[i].SoftName);
  LNode.Values[2]  := Trim(FOfferList.Items[i].SerialNumber + ' ' + FOfferList.Items[i].ActivateNum);
  LNode.Values[3]  := Trim(FOfferList.Items[i].OfferNum);
  LNode.Data := LOffer;
end;
end;
```

children nodes are only populated when a site is clicked. This will then display all offers which exists for said site. Again offerlist is an objectlist

I have had a play around with the custom draw event but I have no idea what options to look at.

Test at custom drawing - OnCustomDrawDataCell:

```
AViewInfo.EditViewInfo.TextColor := clBlack;
AViewInfo.BoundsRect.Width := 200;
//AViewInfo.ContentRect.Width := 200;
AViewInfo.EditViewInfo.Paint(ACanvas);
ADone := True;
```

All this seems to do is bunch all the nodes into the far left of the grid and group all the columns ontop of eachother, whilst still not increasing the width of the root node text columns.

TLDR:
I want to be able to have text from column[0] to not clip but instead either continue into other columns or to overlay other columns. For a tcxtreelist which has been populated by a database and objectlists.

Edit 2:
Added image with a visual example of how it looks now
[image: Example of grid now]

As you can see the 'Company' is getting clipped, I would like that root node to just continue displaying its text across all the columns if needs be. This way I can better sort out the width of other columns to try and get the desired view.

Comment: I think that instead of show the code that you use, you should put a code that demonstrate the problem you are having.

Comment: I think that is where the problem may lie. I don't know how to get the first column, on the root nood, to not clip text when it is longer than the columns width. The few attempts I have had have not done anything close to what I want. But I added them none the less. For me it is rather infuriating as I feel it should be simple to disable clipping for either a set column or for certain levels of nodes. Edit: I am not really sure I can add code to demonstrate the problems I am having as I just don't  know how to remove clipping.